# how can i check if an imageview background is a certain image?

Tags: android, imageview

so far im using something like this

```
if (image.getDrawable() != thisContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.raw.anImage) ) {
    // do something
}
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, comparing two drawables is a pain so just convert them to bitmaps and then compare the bitmaps (much easier solution), here's the code:

```
Bitmap bitmap1 = ((BitmapDrawable)fDraw).getBitmap();
Bitmap bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable)sDraw).getBitmap();

if(bitmap1 == bitmap2)
{
 do some stuff
}
```

Comment: ok it gave me a null pointer exception on Bitmap bitmap1 = ((BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable()).getBitmap(); this is being done in an onitemclicklistener for a gridview. in the adapter i set each view to have a backgroundresource, im not sure why it would give me a null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

try converting the Drawables to `Bitmap` first and then comparing:

```
Bitmap a = ((BitmapDrawable)d1).getBitmap();
Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable)d2).getBitmap();
```