# Check what background is being used in ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I need to be able to tell what background is being used in an ImageView of mine:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="24dp"
    android:layout_height="24dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_globe"
    />
```

How can I check, programmatically, if the background of the above ImageView is `ic_globe`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12207058/how-can-i-check-if-an-imageview-background-is-a-certain-image

Comment: Did you try tag for imageview? ie. setTag(R.drawable.ic_globle)  and latter get the tag and compare the values i.e view.getTag() == R.drawable.ic_globe

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap b1 = ((BitmapDrawable) ((ImageView)findViewById(R.id.icon)).getBackground()).getBitmap();
Bitmap b2 = ((BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_globe)).getBitmap();

if (b1 == b2){
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Matched", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else{
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NOT Matched", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Ya you require to handle nulls for b1 and b2 as if image is not able to get decoded then you will have b1 or b2 as null, that you can implement your self.